# Can't export HTML table value to Excel sheet in Microsoft Edge using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, microsoft-edge

I'm converting one html table to Excel sheet and trying to download it. It's working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but not working in Microsoft Edge browser. I'm providing my code below.

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              var table='exportable';
              var name='Report';
             // console.log('table',table,name);
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
```

Here I can't get any Excel sheet of the required table in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: any workaround today?